# In ruby and rails how to remove hyper link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to this how to remove the hyperlink from this but also display the symbol details(`:number_of_weight`)

```
(<%= link_to data[:number_of_weights], lrs_lane_path(lane.id) %> tones)
```

Comment: if i remove this "link_to data[]" it will show only :number_of_weights no that details

Comment: which result are you trying to print?

Comment: am trying to print the :number_of_weight                         :number_of_weights      =>lrs = lane.all_eligible_lrs_for_service_provider(employed_by_id, time_now).size

Comment: just `<%= data[:number_of_weights]%> tones` does not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<%= data[:number_of_weights] %> tones
```

Just remove the `link_to` helper, do the way mentioned above.

Hope this helps!